# View Ticker questions?

Tags: 7

I try to setup [View Ticker](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_ticker) for a Drupal 7 website.

It would work if I run the following php:

```
<?php
$viewname = 'news_ticker' ;
print views_embed_view ( $viewname );
?>
```

But :

- Could explain me how I choose what is displayed ? 
  I need to display the title of this page : http://www.esii.com/en/actualites
- My site is in french & in english : can the view ticker separe the content for each language?

Comment: This are two question that are barley related.